# Initializing an array class variable in a constructor

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

The following code gives errors:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private int[] values;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 2;
        c = 3;
        values = {a, b, c};
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
    }

}
```

I want values to contain a,b, and c.

I also tried initializing the array outside of the constructor like this.

```
private int[] values = {a, b, c};
```

and initializing it fully inside the constructor like this:

```
int[] values = {a, b, c};
```

but none of these do the trick.

Comment: missing `new` keyword

Comment: Arrays are objects - you need to new one up....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are an object and require you to explicitly use `new` to construct them.

You can use:

```
values = new int[] {a, b, c};
```

Or the even shorter syntax:

```
values = new[] {a, b, c};
```

On a side note, if you're writing the array declaration and initialization in one statement, you can actually write them as you did:

```
int[] values2 = { a, b, c};
```

However, since you have `values` declared as a field, this won't work within the constructor for the values initialization, as you're initializing separate from your declaration.

Comment: But this works and is also an array in the constructor: `int[] values2 = { 1, 2, 3 };`. Why does it work for local variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
int[] values = new int[]{a, b, c};
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
values = new[] { a, b, c };
```

Or

```
values = new int[] { a, b, c };
```

**Further Reading**

- [Arrays Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more examples.